# How to keep the image in the row center in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to keep the image exactly in the center.
so that its position does not change by changing the text around the image.

[image]

```dart
       body: Column(
         children: [
           Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             child: Container(
               height: 50,
                   ],
               child: const Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                 children: [
                   Text('2'),
                   Padding(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                     child: CircleAvatar(
                       backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/2.jpg'),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Text('James Doe'),

                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Row children with Expanded, it will use default flex:1 and then make it center.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded( child: Text('2')),
    Expanded( 
      child: Center(
         child: CircleAvatar(
           backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/2.jpg'),
             ),
          ),
    Expanded(child: Text('James Doe'),),
  ]
)
```